# Recursive Statement Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, python-2.x

Alright So I seem to be having an issue somewhere in my main function . I am able to input both Base and Exponent yet, When It moves onto the next function it outputs a unsupported operand error. I am not exactly sure what I have done wrong. Basically all I am trying to do is input a base and exponent and then output the answer.

I am currently writing in 2.x but, I can also use 3.x
Below is my current code.

```
def power (base, exponent):
    if exponent == 0:
        return base
    else :
        return base * power(base, exponent - 1)


def main():
    base = input('Please Enter An Integer for the Base: ')
    exponent = input ('Please Enter An Exponent: ')
    print(power(base,exponent))
main()
```

Comment: Why would the program be giving me double to answer? For Example, when inputing 2^2 it outputs 8 when it should be 4 or when I do 4^2 it gives me 64 o.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert base and exponent type to be int/float ... Since the type of input statement is str.

The below code works:

```
def power (base, exponent):
    if exponent == 0:
        return 1
    if exponent == 1:
        return base
    else :
        return base * power(base, exponent - 1)

def main():
    base = int(input('Please Enter An Integer for the Base: '))
    exponent = int(input ('Please Enter An Exponent: '))
    print(power(base,exponent))
main()
```

Comment: The OP said the code was running on Py2; on  Py2, `input` automatically `eval`s the input string, so if they entered numbers, it would be `int`/`float`.

Comment: figures I would miss such an easy fix -.- Now to try and figure out why my math is not outputing properly. 4^2 is definitely not 64

Comment: @Yrroth:
if exponent == 1 will work fine
add this before also:
    if exponent == 0:
        return 1

Comment: that would make sense. Figured just returning Base will allow it to function properly